# Vagrant up command not working

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox

When i try to run `vagrant up` i get this error

```
   $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and                                          install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0.4.0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.4.4) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/ve                                         rsions/0.4.4/providers/virtualbox.box
    default:
==> default: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.4.4) for 'virtualbox                                         '!
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Querying NetCfgInstanceId failed (0x00000002)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkI                                         nterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct Han                                         dlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

OS: **Windows 10**

Comment: Have you tried to google "code E_FAIL (0x80004005)" ? Some people say, that reinstalling vbox helped (and some that not): https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12182 + https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=76668

Answer (score 0):

Download this Patch

**[Vbox Win10 Fix](https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/14040/VBox-Win10-fix-14040.exe)**

[issue ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040)

Run this patch and **Leave it running in background**

Then go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` folder.

Right-click on `VirtualBox.exe`,

Go to compatibility option and select `Run in compatible mode` and select `Windows 7`.

Then click ok.

Repeat this proccess for this files `VBoxManage.exe` `VBoxHeadless.exe`